# Ammaps change initial map zoom and coordinates

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

Using Ammaps, how can I change the default zoom and center coordinates for when the map loads? I am using a world map but unfortunately I can't get it to start zoomed in over a specific point.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `zoomLevel`, `zoomLongitude` and `zoomLatitude` in your `dataProvider`.

```
"dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "zoomLevel": 3.5,
    "zoomLongitude": -55,
    "zoomLatitude": 42,
    ...
}
```

Please check this example: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animations-along-lines/

The other option is to use methods after the chart starts. You can use [zoomTo](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#zoomTo) method to zoom to the desired coordinates and the zoom level. Optionally you could try [zoomIn](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#zoomIn) in case you want to rely on the default zoom level and you don't need to change the coordinates.